# Como substituir uma string dependendo da resolução da página

Tags: javascript, html, string

Sou novo em programação, então não sei usar muitos termos técnicos, me desculpem qualquer erro. 
Tenho um arquivo em html de paginação. Quando chego no Mobile, as palavras "Anterior" e "próximo" quebram linha e ficam uma de baixo da outra. Eu gostaria de abreviar elas apenas para "Ant." e "Próx.", mas só quando atingir a resolução com largura de 370px.

Eu não sei mexer ainda nesse código que está no html (Ele já estava pronto), então pensei em usar o JavaScript para substituir a String quando atingir essa largura.

Código HTML:

```
<div class="paginate-links">
{% if paginate.params.pageCount > 1 %}

    {% if paginate.hasPrev %}
        {{ paginate.prev('< Anterior', {'class': 'page-prev page-link'}) }}
    {% endif %}

    {{ paginate.numbers({
        'modulus': 4,
        'separator': '',
        'class': 'page-link',
        'currentClass': 'page-current'
    }) }}

    {% if paginate.hasNext %}
        {{ paginate.next('Próxima >', {'class': 'page-next page-link'}) }}
    {% endif %}

{% endif %}
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

---

Tentei programar algo em JavaScript, mas não estou conseguindo:

```
resolutionMobile = function () {
    var resolutionWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var buttonPrev = document.getElementsByClassName('page-prev');

    if (resolutionWidth <= 370) {
        buttonPrev.replace ("< Anterior", "< Ant.");
    }
};
```

Desde já agradeço todas as ajudas.

Comment: Olá Thiago. Aqui nós preferimos perguntas também que possam ajudar outros desenvolvedores que estejam com problemas parecidos com o seu. Tente editar sua pergunta para deixá-la mais genérica. Ex: como substituir o texto de um link, dependendo da resolução da página.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta ficar escutando o tamanho da tela, quando a mesma chegar aos 370px de largura você altera o texto desejado.

Aplica essa lógica abaixo

```
<!-- @cleefsouza -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JS</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- labels -->    
    <label id="anterior">Anterior</label>
    <label id="proxima">Próxima</label>

    <!-- jquery cdn -->
    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function tamanhoTela(){
            var windowWidth = window.innerWidth; // Largura
            var windowHeight = window.innerHeight; // Altura

            if (parseInt(windowWidth) <= 370) {
                $('#anterior').text('Ant.');
                $('#proxima').text('Próx.');
            } else {
                $('#anterior').text('Anterior');
                $('#proxima').text('Próxima');
            }
        };

        tamanhoTela();

        window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
            tamanhoTela();  
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Eu consegui fazer utilizando esse método. Mas todas as respostas me abriram a mente para outros trabalhos que eu também estava fazendo estilo gambiarra. Agradeço a todos pela ajuda.

Answer (score 9):

Um pouquinho de CSS resolve:

```
Ant<span class="wideonly">erior</span>
```

e aí esconde com um @media:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .wideonly {display:none}
}
```

Este @media vai valer até a largura de 800px (da viewport, seja da página ou do iframe - não é a largura do elemento, é da viewport toda). Usei este valor para fazer a demonstração a seguir, basta ajustar para a largura desejada para o seu projeto.

Muito provavelmente no seu CSS já vai ter algum `@media` cuidando de outros aspectos para mobile, que você poderá aproveitar para inserir o `.wideonly`.

Ainda, se preferir, pode inverter a lógica fazendo por padrão o `span` escondido, e mostrando com `@media ... min-width`, se seu design for *mobile-first*.

Se quiser o pontinho na hora de abreviar, basta usar a mesma lógica, mas colocar um `::after {content:"."}` no elemento onde a palavra abreviada se encontra.

Só não recomendo o uso do `content` para trocar a palavra toda para não atrapalhar a semântica da página.

### Demonstrando

Use o link "página toda"/"fechar" para alternar as duas exibições. Estruturei de uma maneira um pouco diferente do início da pergunta para mostrar uma variação da técnica.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .abrev span {display:none}    /*esconde um pedaço*/
  .abrev::after {content:"."}   /*acrescenta o ponto*/
}
```

```html
<span class="abrev">Ant<span>erior</span></span> |
<span class="abrev">Próx<span>imo</span></span>
```

Comment: Nossa! Realmente, um pouquinho de CSS resolve... Excelente ideia. +1 :)

Answer (score 4):

Você deve criar um listener `resize` para "saber" sempre que a janela tiver o seu tamanho alterado. Algo assim:

```js
function setText() {
  const element = document.querySelector('#el');

  // Você pode usar media queries usando `window.matchMedia`:
  if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 600px)").matches) {
    element.textContent = 'Menor ou igual que 600px';
  } else {
    element.textContent = 'Maior que 600px';
  }
}

// Quando a página carregar, também queremos definir
// o texto corretamente, assim como sempre que a
// janela for modificada.
window.addEventListener('load', setText);
window.addEventListener('resize', setText);
```

```html
<div id="el"></div>
```

No *snippet* acima, clique em "Expandir Trecho de Código" e vá alterando o tamanho da sua janela para testar. :)

#### Referência:

- [`window.matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia);
- [Evento `resize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event).

Comment: Por que o negativo?

Comment: Fiquei curioso tambem. De qq forma meu +1 está dado, muito mais sensato do que usar jQuery para isso, como foi sugerido